# Are there content "triggers" in Liferay CMS?

Tags: nosql, liferay

This could be a newbie question regarding Liferay - sorry for that:

Is there any chance to hook up the saving process in Liferay CMS?
E.g. we'd like to send content to a CDN and a separate NoSQL-database once it was stored in Liferay.

How can we achieve that? Any hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think a hook, either a ModelListener-hook for `JournalArticle` or a ServiceWrapper-hook on the methods that would save the web-content, should do the trick for you.

Or else if you don't want a real-time update you can always create a cron-job in liferay which would look in the specific database tables using Liferay API and do the work for you.